# pymodbus tcp synchronous client unable to trap error when connection fails

Tags: python, connection, modbus, pymodbus

Using the `pymodbus` example from https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus
It is working fine and connecting to the PLC and reading the holding registers.
But I have one issue. When the PLC is switched off, the code is not able to trap the disconnected error.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient
UNIT = 0x1
def run_sync_client():
  client = ModbusClient('192.168.1.190', port=502)  
  client.connect()
  rr = client.read_holding_registers(1, 4, unit=UNIT)
  # follwoing will write value 10 or 20 to address 1 
  rq = client.write_register(4, 20, unit=UNIT)  
  client.close()
  print (rr)
  print (rr.registers) ## This reads from input registers of the Modbus Slave / Server 

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      run_sync_client()
```

I tried, try .. then if client.connect(). Can someone suggest how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below instead of `client.connect()` and `print(rr.registers)`:

```
if client.connect():
    ...  # do stuff

    if not rr.isError():
        print(rr.registers)
    else:
        print(rr)
else:
    print('Connection problem')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with some more reading and trials, I got it to work as follows. I might be wrong. But i want to share my code to help newbies like me to have a starting point. 
The code as follows

```
import logging
UNIT = 0x1


def run_sync_client():
    try:
        #client = ModbusClient('192.168.1.190', port=502)  
        client = ModbusClient('localhost', port=502)  
        client.connect()
        #connected =1

    except:
        print("modbus error")
   # "Read write registeres simulataneously")
    try:
            rr = client.read_holding_registers(1, 4, unit=UNIT)
            # following will write value 10 or 20 to address 1 
            rq = client.write_register(4, 20, unit=UNIT)  
            # close the client
            client.close()
            print (rr)
            print (rr.registers) 
    except Exception as e:
            print ("Modbus Connection returned Error ",e)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_sync_client()
```

This is working fine and getting the values from the plc over tcp. Now i am working on Asynchronous connection. Will get back with some doubts and then some answers (if any) ;)